# PHP - generate a sequential character array of n items composed of a-z and A-Z

Tags: php, arrays, character, sequence

I'm trying to generate a sequential character array of n items with PHP. What I want to do is, if I tell the function to generate the first, let's say, 6000 items, to get something like:

```
Array (
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    ...
    [26] => A
    [27] => B
    [28] => C
    ...
    [5178] => BaF
)
```

I already have some starting parts for the function. I can have the character range with this:

```
array_merge(range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"))
```

I can generate the character sequence like this:

```
if (!empty($count)) {
    if (is_numeric($count)) {
        if ($count > 0) {
            $t = $output[] = "a";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $output[] = ++$t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will actually give me a character sequence going from a to z and, when it hits the character limit, it will go like aa, ab, ac, and so on, until it hits the limit again, and then it will go like aaa, aab, aac, and so on, and so on...

If I substitute `$t = $output[] = "a";` with `$t = $output[] = "A";` it does the same but for the uppercase range.

This is perfectly fine, but I would like to include the uppercase range as well, so... is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own algorithm to achieve what you want. It's quite complicated but I have tried my best to explain it in the comments.

```
$chars = array_merge(range("a", "z"), range("A", "Z"));

/*
 * You can comfortably change the value of numChars
 * to your liking and the code will generate appropriate
 * sequence. For example, if you hardcode the value of $numChars
 * to 3 then you will get a sequence like so:
 * a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc, aaa, aab...
 */
$numChars = count($chars);
$output = array();
$count = 6000;
if (!empty($count)) {
    if (is_numeric($count)) {
        if ($count > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $charPositions = getCharPositions($i, $numChars);
                $str = "";
                foreach ($charPositions as $pos) {
                    $str .= $chars[$pos];
                }
                $output[] = $str;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";

function getCharPositions($num, $base)
{
    /*
     * First we find which section the number belongs to
     * and we find how many positions it has moved forward in that section
     * For example, if you want to loop from a to e then the base will be 5
     * if $num is 27 the result is 'ec'
     * Since, it has 2 characters it's in the second section
     * What it means is that it went from first to last for the first position,
     * ie, a to e, and for the second position it moved 22 steps ahead,
     * which is basically (27 - (5^1))
     */
    $section = 1;
    $limit = $base;
    while (true) {
        $temp = $num - $limit;
        if ($temp < 0) {
            break;
        }
        $num = $temp;
        $limit *= $base;
        $section++;
    }

    /*
     * Once we find out how many steps ahead it has moved in the last section,
     * we just need to convert it into a number with the specified base,
     * the code below is basically something like converting a decimal number to
     * a hexadecimal number, However, each digit of the resultant number is stored
     * separately in an array because each of this digit will actually be used as
     * position to get the character from the characters array
     */
    $positionsFilled = 0;
    $result = array();
    while ($num > 0) {
        $remainder = $num % $base;
        $num = (int)($num / $base);

        array_unshift($result, $remainder);
        $positionsFilled++;
    }

    /*
     * Here we prepend zeros for remaining positions
     * because the length of the string should be the
     * same as the section it belongs to
     */
    while ($positionsFilled < $section) {
        array_unshift($result, 0);
        $positionsFilled++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```